# How to make Windows 11 new context menu appear with just one right click instead of two clicks?

Tags: windows-11, desktop-computer, context-menu

I upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11 and one thing that's been annoying me is when you have an app or folder in maximized view and you go back to the desktop by left-clicking the show desktop in the taskbar, you need to double-click the right mouse button to open the context menu.

I clean installed Windows 11 two times and changed my mouse so it's not my PC that is problematic. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>-clicking opens the old context menu with only 1 click but the new context menu needs 2.

Comment: You can do this with a small registry change  ......     https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-right-click-explorer-menu-show-more-as/ba8dafe4-306a-403b-af0d-10a6d1ca0a9a

Comment: Hi, you didn't read my question. I don't want to revert back to the old context menu. I want to open the new context menu with just 1 click instead of 2.

Comment: The link I posted  shows More as a default  [Windows 11 right click explorer menu - Show More as Default]   ....  I thought that is what you wanted

Comment: @BelowAverageUser - You can’t; You can either use the old context menu or accept the limitations of the new context menu.